# web service, service reference, command line wsdl creation

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, soap, wsdl

I have an app that uses .NET ASMX services to communicate. I have seen some developers use the `wsdl` command through the command line to generate strongly typed classes that didnt depend on an endpoint being in the web.config.

Why would some use the `wsdl` command line instead of using a `service reference` (right-click-> add service reference)? What would you do?

Comment: You can indeed use the "Add service reference" without any problem, if you need the proxy to call to a different URL just instantiate with the constructor which allows you to specify the remote address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that the tecnique that you explain should be useful if you need to talk with an unknow WS, at design time.

I do not see any other good reason to use it, as it provide great flexibility but that flexibility could easilly became pain (without a strict schema in you solution the risk is to introduce runtime errors, hard to find at design time)

Comment: the `wsdl` command generates a strongly typed class. Which will not have any runtime errors, unless the service changes and if it does you are going to have trouble with either way of doing it.

Comment: Sorry if i missunderstood your question, what i mean is that if you need to trasfer data to unknow WS you will dinamically generate the class as you describe, at runtime (so in your designer there are no calsses automatically generated).
You get grat flexibility but on the other hand open the door to a great number of probelm (so i suppose is not a good idea if not strictly necessary)

Comment: ah, what sort of problems?

Comment: EG : every time you generate a class at runtime you create pollution in the appdomain.
To do it right you need to generate the classes in a separte AppDomain and unload it when you need to regenerate such classes, but comunication between AppDomain is a pain

Answer (score 1):

A reason I've done this is so I can simulate an external web service and return test data from it.
Using the `wsdl` command I can create an exact version of the web service I'm expecting to call (which might not be available due to existing on another network for example) and then from the available routines have these return "dummy" responses. By merely adding the service reference you don't have any control over this.